# MWPhotoBrowser into Tabbar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, mwphotobrowser

I use `MWPhotoBrowser` to make an image Gallery. If i make a new controller(push) all work fine. Although i want to add `MWPhotoBrowser` into a custom `ViewController` which is into a `TabBarController`. I got this with these lines of code.

```
[self addChildViewController:browser];

[[self view] addSubview:[browser view]];

[browser didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The problem is that when i change the orientation(rotate the device) only a part of screen works. The rest seems to be dead.I suppose that my view keeps previous frame bounds but i don't know how to change this.

I tried setFrame to self.browser.view but it didn't work.

**The strange is that if i change tab and come back to photos tab all again work properly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue in future this line solved my problem. Maybe it was my mistake that i had forgotten this.So i had to add this line to my **viewDidLoad** method.

```
self.view.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```