# MWPhotobrowser in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, mwphotobrowser

I'm trying to make an image gallery in one of the tab of the Tab bar controller which is a custom view controller. In which Gallery tab contains the thumbnail images and on clicking thumbnail it leads to the full image.

Even though i referred the similar post which is the below one

[MWPhotoBrowser into Tabbar Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966764/mwphotobrowser-into-tabbar-controller)

it's not working out.

I'm trying to achieve in this way

```
    let browser = MWPhotoBrowser(delegate: self)
    browser.displayActionButton = true
    browser.displayNavArrows = false
    browser.displaySelectionButtons = false
    browser.alwaysShowControls = true
    browser.zoomPhotosToFill = false
    browser.enableGrid = true
    browser.startOnGrid = true
    browser.enableSwipeToDismiss = false
    browser.autoPlayOnAppear = false
    browser.setCurrentPhotoIndex(0)

    self.photoBrowserView.addSubview(browser.view)
    self.addChildViewController(browser)
```

where photoBrowserView is a view outlet which is placed excluding the Navigation bar and bottom Tab Bar

this is resulting me in a strange behavior where the image appears to be scattered instead of thumbnail. please find the screenshots below

[image: one out of two thumbnail which is scattered]

Any help is highly appreciated as i am stuck with this since 2 days.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser for Swift